# Vbnet Excel Sort - Null Reference Exception

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop, uipath

Been having difficulty sorting an excel worksheet with vbnet. 
Recorded a macro within the workbook, and tried to convert the code over, but am facing null reference exceptions. Any tips on how to get this sort working?

Thanks

**Code**

```
app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
workbook= app.Workbooks.Open(workbook_name)
worksheet = CType(workbook.Worksheets(worksheet_name),Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
range = CType(worksheet.Range("E4:E"+worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count.ToString),Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)

worksheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(
        Key:=range, _
        SortOn:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortOn.xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, _ 
        DataOption:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)
      With worksheet.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortRows
        .SortMethod = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSortMethod.xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

workbook.Save
workbook.Close
```

**Error message**

```
_Test has thrown an exception

Source: Sort and Filter

Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Exception Type: TargetInvocationException

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at UiPathCodeRunner_2980e99aec2a470db67f8b45c1524fdc.Run(Workbook workbook, Worksheet worksheet, Range range, GC GC, Application app, String worksheet_name, String workbook_name)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at UiPath.Core.Activities.Workflow.CompilerRunner.Run(Object[] args)
   at UiPath.Core.Activities.InvokeCode.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Comment: From your error it seems like something  is not instantiated

Comment: Yes, but I can't figure out what it isn't. The only objects are the workbook and the range, which when stepping through are initialized.

Comment: Have you tryied to initialized them from the beginning?

Comment: I believe so, the code snippet is the full code I use

Comment: Try change this:  app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass  -> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application after this i had an problem with: worksheet.AutoFilter.Sort witch could be fixed hopefully with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20476675/4548398